# Use Camera without using cordova plugins in Ionic project?

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm writing an Hybrid application in Ionic-Framework, it's possible to create a Camera Service using Java Native android code and use in ionic project?

The problem is where should I write my native code and how would I interact with my Ionic Project?

In simple words:

I want to place native code like java in android app and call those native methods from Ionic . Is there a provision to do that without using Cordova plugins ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please tell us why you want implement  Camera without Cordova while Cordova-camera plugin is only for accessing Camera functionality.

Answer (score 2):

i have also been trying to do the same , tried linking up my android code with my ionic code , but it could not be done, and atlast i had to write whole code in ionic to make it work . So u gotta use cordova plugins

Answer (score 1):

YES, it is possible to access through Cordova or Sencha kind of framework

However , there is no provision to do it without having platform agnostic framework like Cordova in between because ionic hybrid applications are designed around browsers unlike React native which is JS based engine (built on Google V8 JS engine) .